# Two colliding particles make different angles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, kinematics

Say we have two particles, each that have mass $m$. In the lab frame, one is at rest, and the other is travelling toward it in the x-direction, after they collide, their mass remains constant, but they are now both moving at angles $\theta$ and $\phi$.

We want to show that $\tan \theta \tan \phi \leq 1$.

My approach was to use the particle abberration formula that I have proved before:

For a particle moving uniformly in a frame S with velocity $\mathbf{u}$, making an angle $\theta$ with the x-axis, if we define $\phi$ to be the angle that is made with the $x^{\prime}$-axis in a second frame $S^{\prime}$, then we have the relationship
\begin{align*}
\tan\phi = \frac{\sin \theta}{\gamma(v)\left(\cos \theta - \frac{v}{u} \right)}
\end{align*}
where $v$ is the velocity of the $S$ frame to the $S^{\prime}$ frame.

However, I am not sure how to start on the problem.. I have been given the instructions to "solve the kinematics problem in a clever choice of frame", but I have no idea what I am meant to be "solving" or what it means to "solve a kinematics problem", it seems kind of an arbitrary thing to ask for. Does it mean to use conservation of 4-momentum to get expressions for the momenta after collision?

Comment: Is this *clever*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics#Interacting_particles ?

Comment: Hi Rob, but what exactly is the interaction term $L_{ab}$?